# using a button to add data from a text input with angular

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs

I'm using angular with a MySQL backend.

I think I'm missing something regarding ng-model.

When I click add new idea, nothing happens.  Any ideas.  I'd had it working, but then I changed some things, so I know it's registering to the database.  Additionally, when it did work, it would only update without a refresh occasionally.  My main goal is getting the adding working again, but if there's something else blatantly wrong, please feel free to give me a hard time.

thanks, all.

html

```
<form>
    <div>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="idea" ng-model="ideaInput">
        <button class="btn btn" type="submit" ng-click="addIdea(ideaInput)">Add 
             New Idea</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

php

```
<?php 
require_once 'db.php'; // The mysql database connection script
if(isset($_GET['idea'])){
$task = $_GET['idea'];
$status = "0";
$created = time();
$query=mysql_query("INSERT INTO ideas(idea,status,created_at)  VALUES ('$idea', '$status', '$created')") or die(mysql_error());
}
```

js controller

```
app.controller('ideasController', function($scope, $http) {
  getIdea(); // Load all available ideas 
  function getIdea(){  
  $http.get("ajax/getIdea.php").success(function(data){
        $scope.ideas = data;
       });
  };
  $scope.addIdea = function (idea) {
    $http.get("ajax/addIdea.php?idea="+idea).success(function(data){
        getIdea();
        $scope.ideaInput = "";
      });
  };

?>
```

This is what used to work.

```
<div class="col-sm-3">
<button ng-click="addNewClicked=!addNewClicked;" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger header-elements-margin"><i class="glyphicon  glyphicon-plus"></i>&nbsp;Add New Idea</button>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3">

<input type="text" ng-model="filterIdea" class="form-control search header-elements-margin" placeholder="Filter Ideas">

</div>
</div></div>
<div class="widget-body ">
<form ng-init="addNewClicked=false; " ng-if="addNewClicked" id="newIdeaForm" class="add-idea">
<div class="form-actions">
<div class="input-group">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="comment" ng-model="ideaInput" placeholder="Add New Idea" ng-focus="addNewClicked">
<div class="input-group-btn">
<button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" ng-click="addIdea(ideaInput)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>&nbsp;Add New Idea</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to add your controller reference in the div:

```
<form>
    <div ng-controller="ideasController">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="idea" ng-model="ideaInput">
        <button class="btn btn" ng-click="addIdea(ideaInput)">Add 
             New Idea</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: no go, but sorry, that was my fault - I have the controller in a div higher up.

Comment: what message you get in the console (browser developer tool)?

Comment: I'm not using any browser tool, just refreshing browser.  Any suggestions.  I included what used to work above.  I was attempting to make it much simpler, where was it was - had all this logic to hide the new idea input, etc.

Comment: what browser are you using? almost all browsers have a default developer tool, hit F12 go to the console tab and look what message you got from there

Comment: I may have gotten it working, but sadly, I'm not sure how.  The worst kind of fix.  I took what I had working and just slowly removed things, until I got to where I wanted to be.  I think it had something to do with my divs.  I may have closed myself out the first time.  Thanks for your help.  I'll give you the answer

Comment: sure no problem sometimes working with the DOM could be messy... cheers